# Parallel cross browser testing with Selenium and TestNG without using testng.xml

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Maven Failsafe + TestNG to run Selenium tests. I know it is possible to pass parameters to my TestNG tests by defining system properties in pom.xml like this:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <browser>firefox</browser>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

My TestNG test refers this property like this:

```
@Parameters("browser")
public void setUpClass(@Optional("firefox") String browser)
{
   ...
}
```

However, I was wondering is it possible to run cross browser tests in parallel without a need to specify a testng.xml file. I was trying something like this but it didn't work. Appreciate if you can help.

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <browser>firefox, chrome</browser>
      </systemPropertyVariables>
      <parallel>tests</parallel>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Is it possible to achieve this with just pom.xml configuration? Because of the multi-module nature of my project, I am not keen in using testng.xml file.

Comment: "I was trying something like this but it didn't work."  What was the problem?  After capturing the value of the browser what are you doing wiht it?

Comment: I want to run selenium tests on multiple browsers in parallel. I will update my question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You may populate all properties in *.properties file and then use it with [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/). [QATools Properties](https://github.com/qatools/properties) will make easy to use them during drivers configuration.

Comment: Thanks @Enot Enotovich for the answer. I will try this out though I was looking for a native solution without using additional plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can run any TestNG test programmatically as well. Check here [TestNG Running programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)
so from maven u just need to call your class with main method having the code to run testng programmatically and read whatever properties you wish from any source (csv, properties, xml, xlsx.,etc..)

Comment: Thanks @Mrunal Gosar for the response. Can you please let me know how can we use this feature in a multi module maven project?

Comment: the above approach is independent of multi module maven project..(or for that matter even independent of maven :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple workaround to achieve the same goal. What I am doing and it helps me to maintain a clean code and not adding to many variations and all.

This is based on the assumption that you are using Jenkins to trigger your tests.

You can create 2 Jenkins jobs on the Jenkins server. And then execute them with different mvn commands.

Such as

`mvn clean test -Dbrowser=firefox`
and
`mvn clean test -Dbrowser=chrome`

Hope this helps.